# How to deal with two tables with huge data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing severe issue with one table having 2 crores of data and other table having service type data which is joining with huge data table 
.

Already I have created Clustered index ,Primary key and NonClustered with covering indexes .I have modifed Varchar columns to Char for space purpose I have used all filter conditions

My table looks like :

```
(2 crores data)
CREATE TABLEA (
ApplicationNO Varchar(25)PK,
Service_type VARCHAR(10),
service_id VARCHAR(10),
ISActive Char(1))

(300 records)
CREATE TABLEB(
service_name Varchar(25),
service_id VARCHAR(10),
service_type VARCHAR(10),
Department_id Char(3))
```

My Query :

```
Select A.Servicename,
Count(A.ApplicationNo),
sum(case when p.IS_Active='Y' then 1 else 0 end )as'Complted',
sum(case when p.IS_Active='N' then 1 else 0 end )as'InComplete'
 from TableA A INNER JOIN TableB  B(Service Data)
ON A.ServiceId = B.ServiceId AND A.ServiceType = B.ServiceType 
Where DateFilters fromDate and ToDate AND S.ISActive = 'Y'
```

After creating indexes still it is taking lot of time I have tried every other way.

Please suggest me possible way.

Comment: Don't be shy.  Tell us what indexes you created.  Also, edit the query to be syntactically correct. (What is "DateFilters", for instance? What is `s.ISAcdtive`?).

Comment: Do these tables have primary keys?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like crore

Comment: yes it have primarykey and datefilters (from date to Todate) ,Isactive means taking all only Active records in huge data table

Comment: "DateFilters fromDate and ToDate" is not valid SQL, and neither of your tables have any dates. Please don't leave out things that might be important.

Comment: `p.IS_Active` what is p ?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Code:**

Equate`A.Service_Id = B.Service_id` instead of `A.ServiceId = B.ServiceName`

As **service name** not match with **Service id**

Use this code:

```
Select A.Servicename,
Count(A.ApplicationNo),
sum(case when p.IS_Active='Y' then 1 else 0 end )as'Complted',
sum(case when p.IS_Active='N' then 1 else 0 end )as'InComplete'
 from TableA A INNER JOIN TableB  B(Service Data)
ON A.ServiceId = B.Service_id AND A.ServiceType = B.ServiceType 
Where DateFilters fromDate and ToDate AND S.ISActive = 'Y'
```

Comment: i didn't understand what you have given @Kavin Chakaravarthi

Comment: as per ur query u have equated .service id to servicename.

Comment: it's a typo sorry here i have used Service_id only